# Will DG31PR motherboard support GTX 550ti?

Tags: graphics-card

Will my DG31PR motherboard support GTX 550ti? The processor is core 2 duo 2.66GHz.

Comment: What makes you think it won't?  What make/model of GTX 550ti is it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I apologies for the previous comment. It is asus Nvidia GTX 550 Ti . http://www.nvidia.in/object/product-geforce-gtx-550ti-in.html . Because some people feel that having high end GPU with core 2 duo wont work. That is what my doubt is.

Comment: @GTXhere - If your motherboard supports the card then it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't listen to "some people" as they obviously have no idea what they're talking about.  ;)

Your CPU has little to no bearing on video card compatibility.  Mainly it's connector type, then power requirements, then driver availability.

So if your motherboard has an available PCIe 2.0 16x slot (which [your's does](http://ark.intel.com/products/50375/Intel-Desktop-Board-DG31PR)), your power supply can provide the additional power required by the card (for that card, about 116W above what the rest of the system is using), and there is a driver for that card for your OS, then you should be fine.

Comment: Then I think I should be fine. So you mean that processor has nothing to do with GPU?

Comment: Well it has SOMETHING to do with it, but not in the context of hardware compatibility. :)

Comment: Ok. I will check the other software compatibility.